# Как склеить последовательно датафреймы pandas на основе дат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть два фрейма данных: A, B. Хочу получить фрейм C в виде последовательной склейки A и B на основе столбца дат, но так, чтобы в случае совпадающих дат в склейку были записаны данные из B.

Подскажите, как это сделать красиво через `merge` или `concate` или еще что-то?

Сейчас получаю первый элемент из B, нахожу его номер в A и перезаписываю через `append`, начиная с номера в A. Громоздко.

Даты в формате `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

[image: Примеры датасетов]

Comment: Почему у вас пример данных в виде скриншота опять?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какова всё таки причина игнорирования просьб, давать данные текстом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант решения, основанный на удалении дубликатов дат:

```
C = pd.concat([A, B], ignore_index).drop_duplicates(subset="DT", keep="last")
```

Comment: Гениально. Благодарю. Разбираюсь с написанным. особенно в первом ответе. Подскажите можно ли сделать так что бы сразу дозапиываю A. без использования C

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, конечно, просто замените `C = ...` на `A = ...` )

Comment: :))) так и делала. Имела ввиду без приравнивания. Что то типа: A.volshebstvo(B) . Но видимо на скорости не отразится. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Отфильтруйте значения в `A` и склейте с `B`:

```
C = pd.concat([A.loc[~A["DT"].isin(B["DT"])], B], ignore_index=True)
```

PS данный код не тестировался по причине отсутствия в вопросе воспроизводимого примера данных